# Multiobjective optimization involving convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am working on solving a multi-objective and I would appreciate some guidance and help.

I have basically three types of variables (inputs)

(i) Collections of variable of mixed variable type ==> $\overrightarrow{x} $

(ii) Multiple instantiation of single type ==> $\overrightarrow{\delta}, $ with component $ \delta_i$ where i = 1, 2, ....10

iii) Multiple instantiation of single type ==> $\overrightarrow{B}, $ with component B_j where j = 1, 2, .... 6

For any particular components of $B = B_1$, the output is given by:

$$\overrightarrow{y^1}  =  f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\delta}, B_1) $$

Please notice that $\delta_i$ is directly mapped on ith component of $y_i^1$

Similar relation exists for other instantiation of $B = B_1, B_2, B_3 ... , B_6 $

$$\overrightarrow{y^2}  =  f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\delta}, B_2) $$
$$\overrightarrow{y^3}  =  f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\delta}, B_3) $$

..
$$\overrightarrow{y^6}  =  f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\delta}, B_6) $$

We can stack these objective function column wise to make a multiobjective function.

Basically, the plot of data with $\overrightarrow{\delta} $ and B (dependence on $\overrightarrow{x}) not shown) looks like this:
[image]

It's reasonable to assume that all components are convex.

I am still in the planning stage of how to approach this optimization. So, I would appreciate some guidance from gurus.
I would prefer some gradient based optimization.
If the scalarization is suggested, then there is very good justification to allow for equal weighting of all terms.

Comment: Each of your multiple objectives $y_{i}^{j}$ is a vector- in what sense do you want to optimize these vectors individually?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks a lot for the quick response. I realized that my notations were confusing, particularly the way I was showing subscript over "i". My apologies. I have tried to make the language of question clearer.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Let me take the example of multi-objective $$\overrightarrow{y^1}  =  f(\overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\delta}, B_1) $$ Each of 10 components of $ \overrightarrow{\delta} $ has one-to-one mapping to $ \overrightarrow{y^1} $ So, the construction of final multi-objective is two step process

Comment: Is $\vec{y}^{3}$ a vector (as indicated by the arrow) or a scalar?  If its a vector, in what sense is it one of your multiple objectives?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have added the plot of my data. This will give you some idea about what I am trying to do.